# What's the difference between adding DAY_OF_MONTH, DAY_OF_WEEK or DAY_OF_YEAR to Calendar?

Tags: java, calendar

I want to get the day before yesterday with Calendar, this is the code I use.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date());

// What's the difference between the following three lines?
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -2);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -2);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -2);

System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

The first parameter of `cal.add()` should be a number, the number could be `DAY_OF_MONTH`, `DAY_OF_WEEK`, or `DAY_OF_YEAR`, but I'm sure which one I should use. I tried them all and it seemed that all of them worked very well. Could someone tell me what's the difference between those three lines I highlighted in the code? I didn't find a clear explanation about it in the Java doc.